# "clear: both" is clearing too much. Is this normal behaviour or is it a browser bug?

Tags: html

I have the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/agLap/

```css
.navigation{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}

.content{
    background-color: #00FF00;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.first{
    background-color: #0000FF;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.second{
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.third{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="first">first</div>
    <div class="second">second</div>
    <div class="third">third</div>
</div>
```

Problem is: I want the yellow box to appear inside the green box, but underneath the 2 other boxes.

So I'm doing

```
clear: both;
```

on the yellow box. But that is clearing **too much**. It's also clearing the red navigation div. And it's not even inside that box.

Should this be how "clear: both" works or is this a browser bug?

Comment: It seems to work for me by removing the clear in `.third` altogether - is that what you wanted or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get my jsfiddle code correct. This is the correct code:http://jsfiddle.net/agLap/  Removing the clear, puts the div next to the other 2 divs

Comment: Try removing the `clear: both` for `third` and give the content a height... I tried in Firebug, worked...

Comment: I believe this does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/agLap/4/

Comment: Even works when you add a few more top boxes. http://jsfiddle.net/agLap/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 years later (with slightly better css skills :-) ), I found good solution to my own problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kzjyfLto/

Just replace the

```
margin-left: 100px;
```

with

```
float: left;
```

This makes the content block stick to the navigation block and seems to create a clean slate for the content of the content block.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this JSFiddle, This is what I think you want: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Brae/4/): http://jsfiddle.net/2Brae/4/.

- You are floating navigation to the left, which does that.
- Then you want to float the content div to the right of that navigation.
- Set your heights for your interior divs
- Then under all your floats, use `<div class="clear"></div>` to clear the floated elements.

Comment: Now that I read your answer, it's more or less what I was looking for 7 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

- `clear: both;` clears both left and right;
- `clear: left;` clears left;
- `clear: right;` clears right.

Completely, yes - if you clear left, it clears everything that is floated left.

There are ways to go around this though.
If you clear inside a floated container, it does not clear floats outside that container - try floating your `.content` container.

---

This article is probably useful to you: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

Some advanced reading - the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules

Comment: thx, now I have better understanding floats. Modified my jsfiddle to the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/z9JMX/